# Prefix and suffix strings to each output line from command

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have ran into a problem trying to write a Bash script. When `grep` outputs, it returns (usually) many lines. I would like to prefix and suffix a string to each of these output lines.

I would also like to note that I'm piping `ls` into `grep`, like:

```
ls | grep
```

Comment: You shouldn't parse `ls` - it's bad juju. Also, does it have to be `grep`? And can you give some example output?

Comment: What do you want your script to do if the filename contains a newline?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With sed:

```
ls | grep txt | sed 's/.*/prefix&suffix/'
```

Comment: Or, `sed` being a superset of `grep`: `ls | sed -n '/txt/s/.*/prefix&suffix/p'` or `ls | sed -n 's/.*txt.*/prefix&suffix/p'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank you for this hint.

Comment: If you see unexpected results, check for LF newline encoding. With CR/LF your sed, or any tool for that matter, might output some garbage.

Answer (score 12):

With `sed`:

```
ls | grep pattern | sed -e 's/^/prefix/' -e 's/$/suffix/'
```

But note, this suffers from problems with filenames with line feeds, and all the assorted problems of parsing `ls` which is generally a bad idea.

With perl

```
perl -e 'print "prefix".$_."suffix\n" for grep { m/somepattern/} glob "*"'
```

Note - perl `grep` can take a pattern - like the `grep` command, but you can also do things like apply file tests.

E.g.

```
grep {-d} glob "*" #filters directories.
grep { (stat)[9] > time() - 60 } glob "*" #reads file mtime and compares.
```

Within `grep` the default iterator `$_` is set to the current element value, so you can apply `sed`/`grep` style regex, or perform a variety of tasks based on `$_`.

Comment: How would I include a variable as a suffix/prefix in your first example using ´sed´?

Comment: Change the quotes to `“` and just use em.

Answer (score 4):

In this case GNU `find` lets you do all these things in one go, eliminating pipes and potentially troublesome parsing of `ls`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[^.]*' \
  -regextype posix-extended -regex "MYPATTERN" \
  -printf 'SOMEPREFIX %f SOMESUFFIX\n'
```

(`find` is not a good way to arbitrarily modify the output of other commands, of course!)

Some notes:

- `-maxdepth 1` and `-name [^.]*` make name matching work the same as a plain `ls` (or `ls .`). You can use any shell-style glob, but note that "*" will match a leading "." in a name<sup>†</sup> unlike `bash`, so `[^.]*` means anything that *doesn't have* a leading "."
- MYPATTERN is a proper POSIX ERE (default type is Emacs, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html)), **but** it must match the entire filename (including the `./` prefix) so use something like `.*thing.*` instead of just `thing`
- you can *probably* just use one of `-name`/`-regex` instead of both (e.g. -regex "[^.].*MYPATTERN.*"
- `-printf` supports [lots of things](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Format-Directives), `%n` is the unadorned file or directory name
- beware `find` (contrary to `ls`) doesn't sort the list of file names.
- it assumes the file names constitute valid text in the current  locale.

> <sup>†</sup> (this can depend on your version of `find` though, check the "STANDARDS CONFORMANCE" section of your man page)

As a possible alternative with no external programs required, `bash` has `compgen` which, among other things, expands globs, equivalent to an `ls` with no options:

```
compgen -P "someprefix>" -S "<somesuffix" -G "pattern"
```

This handles filenames with whitespace, including newlines. `compgen -G "*"` should provide the same output as a plain `ls` (but note that `ls *` is a different thing entirely). You'll still need `grep`, and this may or may not solve the problem, but it's worth a mention.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can just use globs here. With the `extglob` option enabled (which enables ksh88 globs), bash globs are functionally equivalent to regexps so you don't need `grep`:

```
printf 'prefix%ssuffix\n' *foo*
```

For all the filenames that contain `foo` (equivalent to using `grep foo` with the extra benefit that it works properly if filenames contain newline characters).

```
shopt -s extglob
printf 'prefix%ssuffix\n' foo+([[:digit:]]).jpg
```

(as equivalent to `grep -E '^foo[[:digit:]]+\.jpg$'`)

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
ls | grep | awk '$0="prefix"$0"suffix"'
```

*`"prefix"` and `"suffix"` are string literals, so replace the text with whatever you want.*

---

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099492/2089675

Answer (score -1):

`sed` and `find` solutions are challenged if your prefix/suffix include regex key characters or if want to pass an environment variable (instead of an immediate value), `xargs`+`echo` might be more appropriate here.

With environment variable:

```
ls | grep p | xargs -I % sh -c "echo $PATH/%"
```

With an inline:

```
ls | grep p | xargs -I % sh -c "echo `pwd`/%"
```

Comment: The names of the files (and the contents of `$PATH` and the output of `pwd`) end up interpreted as shell code! So that makes it a code injection vulnerability.

Comment: `$PATH` is the search path for executables, you may be confusing with `$PWD`.

Comment: `xargs` comes with its own problems. It will choke on quotes, backslashes and leading white space.

Comment: `echo` also can't be used to output arbitrary data.